# When I do Flask run, it shows error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'. Can anyone help me with this?

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug, flask-session

the exact error I get is :

```
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "application", an ImportError was raised:Traceback      (most recent call last):
File "/home/harshit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in     locate_app
__import__(module_name)
File "/home/harshit/Documents/project1/application.py", line 18, in <module>
Session(app)
File "/home/harshit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_session/__init__.py", line 54,    in __init__
self.init_app(app)
File "/home/harshit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_session/__init__.py", line 61, in init_app
app.session_interface = self._get_interface(app)
File "/home/harshit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_session/__init__.py", line 93, in _get_interface
config['SESSION_USE_SIGNER'], config['SESSION_PERMANENT'])
File "/home/harshit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_session/sessions.py", line 313, in __init__
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'werkzeug.contrib'
```

I am trying to import sessions from Flask

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Werkzeug 1.0.0 has removed deprecated code, including all of `werkzeug.contrib`. You should use alternative libraries for new projects. `werkzeug.contrib.session` was extracted to [secure-cookie](https://pypi.org/project/secure-cookie/).

---

If an existing project you're using needs something from `contrib`, you'll need to downgrade to Werkzeug<1:

```
pip3 install Werkzeug<1
```

Comment: if this doesnt work, just try between ""
`pip install "werkzeug<1"`

Answer (score 8):

You will need to downgrade `werkzeug` version  from **1.0.0** to **0.16.0**

This solved the problem for me.

**Just run the following commands in your project**:

`python3 -m pip uninstall werkzeug`

and then

`python3 -m pip install werkzeug==0.16.0`

Answer (score 6):

Either downgrade the version to 0.16.0 or replace `werkzeug.contrib.cache` with `cachelib`.

I can highly recommend upgrading the package. The deprecated module `werkzeug.contrib` is very easy to replace!

Install `cachelib` and replace all imports from:

```
from werkzeug.contrib.cache import FileSystemCache
```

to

```
from cachelib import FileSystemCache
```

Answer (score 1):

Found that module in the source code. Now it can be imported with the following line

```py
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
```

Comment: Can you add some detail? We like fully explained answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you still need deprecated code from `werkzeug.contrib`, you can downgrade Werkzeug version to less than 1.

```
pip install Werkzeug<1
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.8

```
python3 -m pip uninstall werkzeug
python3 -m pip install werkzeug
python3 -m pip install flask-session
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this addresses the question? I tried this and it didn't do anything. How did this work for you or why did you expect that this would remedy the issue?

Comment: this got me to where mine worked because of the package itself -- i typed pip uninstall werkzeug then pip install werkzeug and it worked after that

Answer (score 0):

After downgrading werkzeug:

`pip install werkzeug==0.16.0`

If you get the following:
`flask 2.0.2 requires Werkzeug>=2.0, but you have werkzeug 0.16.0 which is incompatible`

Consider doing:`pip install flask==1.1.1`

Answer (score 0):

For my upgrade (0.15.5 -> 2.2.3) Everything is moved or removed from contrib to other modules. I recomend going to the [documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/) for your specific version of werkzeug and searching the library you are trying to import. I found mine!

```
from werkzeug.middleware.profiler import ProfilerMiddleware
app = ProfilerMiddleware(app)
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on Alexander P's answer: If you're using this on Werkzeug 0.16.0

```
from werkzeug.contrib.fixers import ProxyFix
```

You can replace it with this for Werkzeug 2.2.3

```
from werkzeug.middleware.proxy_fix import ProxyFix
```